# Facebook Deep Linking not working on Android

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook deep linking feature according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking.

I have followed step by step instructions:

- Created FB app
- Added FB sdk (4.13.2) to Android app

When I run the app, it is detected by Facebook, verified on the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/

[image]
I also created an `Activity` to handle deep links. AndroidManifest configuration:

```
    <activity android:name=".DeeplinkActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="deeplink.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/openapp"
                android:scheme="deep" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`DeeplinkActivity` opens if started from adb via:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "deep://deeplink.com/openapp" com.example.rps
```

This is Android configuration under Facebook app settings:
[image]

Please note that fully qualified Class Name (`com.example.rps.DeeplinkActivity`) is also not working.

I tried testing deep links via Deeplink Tester, on the App Ads Helper page (link above)

[image]

I receive notification on my phone from Facebook app, saying "Tap to launch your deep link", but nothing happens, my app is never started.

What am I missing?

Comment: Same problem here :/

Comment: have you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 2):

When you receive notification on your phone from Facebook app, saying "Tap to launch your deep link" you have to open Facebook app on the "notifications" tab and click on the received notification THERE, that will start your app (if it's installed, that is).

If you just click on the notification in the action bar nothing will happen. Confusing I know, since it blatantly states "Tap to launch your deep link".

Comment: I don't think this is the solution to the problem at hand. Could you explain in more detail what you mean?

Comment: No the notification received in fb app is not opening